# Get file names inside DLL

Tags: c#, reflection, embedded-resource

it is possible to get the names of the files inside a DLL, for example I have this structure and when I run my program I want to get the names of the files that are inside the "Images" folder in this case **"es-AR.ico and en-US.ico"**. Thx!

**Project**

[image]

Comment: So you are talking specifically about project files with Build as Resource?

Comment: Depending on build type, you might look for embedded resources:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3089/understanding-embedded-resources-in-visual-studio